# Displaying child form immediately after MDI form is completely displayed

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, mdi

I've MDI winform with a top panel displaying picture and a navigation menu populated from a database on the left. I wanted to display a default child form immediately after the MDI form is displayed. I've used DevExpress WaitForm before displaying everything. However, the top panel remains blank until the child form is completely displayed. What can I do to display the child form after every component of the MDI is displayed. I tried threads but didn't figure out how to properly manage it. Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the child form doing that it is blocking the painting of the MDI form?

Comment: The child form contains a xtraReport control that generates reports from the database

Comment: Use a splash screen to cover up ugly initialization artifacts.

Comment: In fact, the child form has a WaitForm and it's the one that's hanging everything up. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> The child form contains a xtraReport control that generates reports from the database

Sounds like your child form is blocking the main window with its fetching of database data and report generation.

Consider using another thread to fetch the data from the database.  Once you have all the data, have the UI thread set the data source property (or equivalent) on the `xtraReport` control.

For threading you could use:

- An explicit `Thread` (not recommended)
- A `Task` though you may need to thread-marshal to your UI thread
- An `async` method that you can `await` (recommended).  This makes it much easier to do the work on another thread then automatically marshal the results to your UI thread where you can update `xtraReport`